# Hbase authentication wihout Kerberos or AD/LDAP

Tags: authentication, authorization, hbase, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm actually trying to make some custom security setups in a **HDP** cluster (not Kerberized). The use case is *hbase and kafka must implement authorization but wihthout using kerberos. Only human mistakes must be avoided, so there's no reason for passwords*. All in Java.

Of course there's no authorization without authentication (which is where Kerberos does its job). I was able to implement authorization on Kafka brokers (this one, even on a kerberized cluster, the brokers can be configured to change from `GSSAPI` to `PLAIN`), making my own implementation of a `LoginModule` that just reads a **Jaas** file:

```
KafkaClient 
{
   my.package.project.authentication.NamePlateLoginModule required
   username=stuckuvurfluw;
};
```

Yes I know, a dummy authentication =). As I said, there's no need to secure data, just avoid human mistakes. So, on KafkaBrokers, I just needed to make some changes to the properties in order to change the behaviour and expect `PLAIN` authentication. Setting up `kafka acls` to allow only *stuckuvurfluw* user was made the [same old way](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html):

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh (..) --add --allow-permissions User:stuckuvurfluw (...)
```

One done.. But oh Hbase. I am not able to find any way to setup authentication without using Kerberos. No property value found for `hbase-site.xml` or other configuration properties on client side.

The question is, is there anyway, or some other implementation other than Kerberos, in which I can base my own "Dummy" implementation, similar to the one made for Kafka? Thanks in advance! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this helps:

There's no way.

A valuable comment from [Samson Scharfrichter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5162372/samson-scharfrichter):

> Speaking about Hadoop in general, the *SIMPLE* authentication mode does
> ensure that *"Only human mistakes must be avoided"* > client identity is
> **guessed** on client side from (a) env variable `HADOOP_USER_NAME` and (b)
> failing that, the current Linux or Windows session user as reported by
> the JVM. If HBase supports ACLs in *SIMPLE* mode (like HDFS does) then
> you've got your "dummy" authentication/authorization out of the box...

Comment: Speaking about Hadoop in general, the _SIMPLE_ authentication mode does ensure that  _"Only human mistakes must be avoided"_ > client identity is **guessed** on client side from (a) env variable `HADOOP_USER_NAME` and (b) failing that, the current Linux or Windows session user as reported by the JVM. If HBase supports ACLs in _SIMPLE_ mode (like HDFS does) then you've got your "dummy" authentication/authorization out of the box...

Comment: Thanks a lot Samson for your time. I would have given the bounty, but expired 3 days ago. So appreciated.